# Determine $U^{\perp}$.

Tags: definite-integrals, vector-spaces

> Let $U = \{1,\sin(x),\cos(x),\sin(2x),\cos(2x)\}$ and $V=\{f:[-\pi,\pi]\to\mathbb{R}|f continuous\}$ with the scalar product: $\langle f,g\rangle=\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)g(x)dx.$ Find $U^{\perp}$.

So we know that:

$$U^{\perp}=\{w\in V|\langle u,w\rangle=0,\forall u\in U\}$$

but if we do $\langle f,1\rangle = \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)dx = 0.$ but this happens *iff* $f(-x)=-f(x).$

So then my guess is:

$$U^{\perp}=\{f\in V|f(-x)=-f(x)\}$$

But are they all of them?

Comment: If $f$ is an odd function then $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) \, dx=0$ but the converse is false. I think there is no simple description of $U^{\perp}$ if you are restricting yourself to continuous functions.

Comment: $U^{\perp}$ will be spanned by the set $\{sin(nx), cos(mx) : n, m>2\}$ I should think.

Comment: @Paul but why..?

Comment: I assume $U$ is a basis of a vector space. Since $1$ belongs to $U,$ the functions from $U^{\perp}$ are odd. Then the basis of the orthogonal complement is $U^{\perp}=\{\sin(nx)\},\;n\in \mathbb{N}, n\neq 1,2$

Comment: The set $U\cup W$ where $W = \{sin(nx), cos(mx) : n, m>2\}$ is a basis for $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$ and each element of $W$ is orthogonal to $U$.

Comment: @Paul I understand, but how did you come up with that answer?

Comment: Clearly all of $U\cup W$ is in V. $W$ must span the part of $V$ not spanned by $U$ since $V$ is dense in $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$. That still does not characterize $U^{\perp}$, as you would need to close the vector space spanned by $W$ in the sup topology of V.